# native compiled stored procedure sp_getapplock alternative

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, memory-optimized-tables

tldr; what is alternative of sp_getapplock in the native compiled stored procedure.

I have a memory-optimized table and few indexes on it. it is mission critical app. I am using a memory-optimized table since is does minimal logging. I am developing order matching/trade matching engine. one order is inserted at a time and matched with open orders. it is not a bulk operation. I have tried with regular table, but I was not able to achieve throughput I require. the memory-optimized table has solved throughput issue.

I want to restrict SQL server to not run more than one instance of the stored procedure. in the regular stored procedure, this can be achieved with sp_getapplock. how can I achieve this with the natively compiled stored procedure?

I googled and did not found an answer.

Comment: If you only allow one process at a time to access the table via the stored proc, aren't you defeating the purpose of using a fast memory optimised table? won't that then be a bottleneck?

Comment: @MitchWheat we are using the memory-optimized table only because they are faster. as per business rule, we can not process multiple requests in parallel.

Comment: then why not do it in application memory?

Comment: @MitchWheat it is financial data, I want to guarantee the durability of the transaction.

Comment: that's why we have lock() !

Comment: @MitchWheat in application memory, we can use lock(), but once we say transction is complete, it should be durable, even if machine/application crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173141/discussion-between-arjun-vachhani-and-mitch-wheat).

Answer (score 1):

One method is to execute `sp_getapplock` in a outer stored procedure that wraps the call to the native proc:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_NativeProcWrapper
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
    EXEC sp_getapplock 'dbo.usp_NativeProc', 'Exclusive', 'Transaction';
    EXEC dbo.usp_NativeProc;
    EXEC sp_releaseapplock 'dbo.usp_NativeProc', 'Transaction';
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, any other cleaner way to do it in the natively compiled stored procedure.

Comment: Native procs can only execute other native procs so it is just not possible to execute `sp_getapplock` from the native proc directly. This work--around is fairly straightforward, and a good one for your need, IMHO. If you are concerned about performance, you could run single-threaded tests with and without the wrapper. I wouldn't expect the difference to be all that significant.